# Regex for URL with querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following javascript with regex to test url string.

```
var url = window.location.pathname;

// create regexp to match current url pathname and remove trailing slash if 
// present as it could collide with the link in navigation in case 
// trailing slash wasn't present there
urlRegExp = new RegExp(url == '/' ? window.location.origin + '/?$' : url.replace(/\/$/, '')); 

// now grab every link from the navigation
$('.page-sidebar a').each(function () {
    // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
     if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
         $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
     }
});
```

But this regex doesnt include the querystring. How can I do that?

Comment: relavant question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links/37687

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could match a string with something like this and construct from it what you want.

```
var rx = new RegExp("^(?:([^:\\/?#]+):)?(?:\\/\\/((?:(([^:@]*)(?::([^:@]*))?)?@)?([^:\\/?#]*)(?::(\\d*))?))?((((?:[^?#\\/]*\\/)*)([^?#]*))(?:\\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?)");

var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053753/regex-for-url-with-querystring?a0b&c=d&e=f#anchor";

var val = url.match(rx);

val.forEach(function (part) {
    var result = $("#result");
    var $text = $("<p>").text(part);
    result.append($text);
});
```

You can play with this code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Rt8rm/)